# jQuery swapsies does not work for multiple moves

Tags: jquery, css, bubble-sort, jquery-effects

i have used jQuery for swapping of cards. i want to let the swapping played untill array having values one by one

i have made function based on array .

how i can overcome this the result should be once the first pair from array got swapped then second pair should start swapping

i also have seen some example of callback function because jquery plugin `JQuery Swapsies plugin` returning with the callback function once swapping done

**HTML**

```
    <div class="Blocks">
            <div class="cards" id="div_1"><img src="images/ilogo.png"></div>
            <div class="cards" id="div_2"><img src="images/ilogo.png"></div>
            <div class="cards" id="div_3"><img src="images/ilogo.png"></div>
            <div class="cards" id="div_4"><img src="images/ilogo.png"></div>
            <div class="cards" id="div_5"><img src="images/ilogo.png"></div>
            <div class="cards" id="div_6"><img src="images/ilogo.png"></div>
            <div class="cards" id="div_7"><img src="images/ilogo.png"></div>
            <div class="cards" id="div_8"><img src="images/ilogo.png"></div>
            <div class="cards" id="div_9"><img src="images/ilogo.png"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="actionbar">
        <a href="javascript://" class="go-swap">Go Swap!</a>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
<style>
    .cards {
        width:160px;
        height:200px;
        border:1px solid #00F;
        border-radius:5px;
        float:left;
        margin:5px;
        text-align:center;
        padding:5px;
    }
    .cards img
    {
        width:90%;
        margin-top:10%;
    }
    .Blocks
    {
          display: block;
        width: 550px;
        height: auto;
        float: left;
            clear:both;
    }
    .actionbar
    {
        clear:both;
        float:left;
        width:100%;
    }
</style>
```

**Script**

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-swapsies.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() { 

            var swapperarray = [];
            swapperarray[0] = ['div_3', 'div_1'];
            swapperarray[1] = ['div_3', 'div_4'];
            swapperarray[2] = ['div_7', 'div_8'];
            swapperarray[3] = ['div_9', 'div_2'];
            swapperarray[4] = ['div_2', 'div_7'];
            swapperarray[5] = ['div_5', 'div_6'];
            swapperarray[6] = ['div_8', 'div_7'];
            swapperarray[7] = ['div_1', 'div_4'];
            swapperarray[8] = ['div_6', 'div_9'];
            swapperarray[9] = ['div_3', 'div_7'];


            $.each( swapperarray, function( key, value ) {
                 var valuers = value;
                 var arrasssy = valuers.toString().split(",");
                 GoCards(arrasssy[0],arrasssy[1])
            });
    });
    function GoCards(div1,div2)
    {
        //alert("sdv")
        $('#'+div1).swap({  
                    target: div2, // Mandatory. The ID of the element we want to swap with  
                    opacity: "1", // Optional. If set will give the swapping elements a translucent effect while in motion  
                    speed: 1000, // Optional. The time taken in milliseconds for the animation to occur  
                    callback: function() { // Optional. Callback function once the swap is complete  
                    }  
         }); 
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @PunithJain that has to be seprated in value there will be two more sub items coma seprated which have to be seprate and that will swape each other didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used recursive function to dynamically create options for swap check out the link

http://plnkr.co/edit/fmDsGTcmIMy2ppobRD8v?p=preview

```js
// Code goes here
 $(document).ready(function() {

    var swapperarray = [];
    swapperarray[0] = ['div_3', 'div_1'];
    swapperarray[1] = ['div_3', 'div_4'];
    swapperarray[2] = ['div_7', 'div_8'];
    swapperarray[3] = ['div_9', 'div_2'];
    swapperarray[4] = ['div_2', 'div_7'];
    swapperarray[5] = ['div_5', 'div_6'];
    swapperarray[6] = ['div_8', 'div_7'];
    swapperarray[7] = ['div_1', 'div_4'];
    swapperarray[8] = ['div_6', 'div_9'];
    swapperarray[9] = ['div_3', 'div_7'];
    
   $('#'+swapperarray[0][0]).swap(createOptions(swapperarray))

             
});
    
function createOptions(swapperarray){
   var obj = {};
   var pair = swapperarray.shift();
    obj.target = pair[1];
    obj.opacity = "1";
    obj.speed = 1000;
  if(swapperarray.length > 0)
  {
    obj.callback = function (){ /* add class to div here*/ $('#'+swapperarray[0][0]).swap(createOptions(swapperarray)) }
  }
  else 
  {
    obj.callback = function (){ /* add class to div here*/}
  }
  return obj;
}
```

```css
.cards {
        width:160px;
        height:200px;
        border:1px solid #00F;
        border-radius:5px;
        float:left;
        margin:5px;
        text-align:center;
        padding:5px;
    }
    .cards img
    {
        width:90%;
        margin-top:10%;
    }
    .Blocks
    {
          display: block;
        width: 550px;
        height: auto;
        float: left;
            clear:both;
    }
    .actionbar
    {
        clear:both;
        float:left;
        width:100%;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://biostall.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/jquery-swapsies.js"></script>

   
    <div class="Blocks">
      <div class="cards" id="div_1">
        div1
      </div>
      <div class="cards" id="div_2">
        div2
      </div>
      <div class="cards" id="div_3">
        div3
      </div>
      <div class="cards" id="div_4">
        div4
      </div>
      <div class="cards" id="div_5">
        div5
      </div>
      <div class="cards" id="div_6">
        div6
      </div>
      <div class="cards" id="div_7">
        div7
      </div>
      <div class="cards" id="div_8">
        div8
      </div>
      <div class="cards" id="div_9">
        div9
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="actionbar">
      <a href="javascript://" class="go-swap" >Go Swap!</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Worked perfactly !! Can add class to all the div once animation done for all the  div . it will be in the createOptions Function right ?

Comment: createOptions as a callback back function inside that add class to div